# Can i run my website which is developed in php and mysql without apache server (without wamp or xampp ))?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Can i run my website which is developed in php and mysql without apache server (without wamp or xampp )) ?

Comment: Try lamp, or is that excluded as well?

Comment: Why exclude Apache ?

Comment: apache is a Webserver. You can use every webserver you want to bring the requests to PHP. apache is just used by the majority of websites.

Comment: use nginx with fcgi then!

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can. But Apache is usually a good solution.

You can run your website using [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) directly, or with [Xamp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)/[Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)/[Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/)/Lamp, or even Nginx.

To use Apache directly you can do something like :
`sudo apt-get install php5 apache2 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5`

Otherwise, you could use Microsoft IIS.

PHP includes a built-in server using -S option of PHP. But this is a development server, **do not use it in production.**

Answer (score 0):

To run PHP applications you have to install Apache, PHP and MySQL. In fact it is difficult for beginners to install these bundles separately and combine them to run PHP CODE. XAMPP does that for you with just a few clicks.

1) Install xampp 
2) run xampp 
3) save you file with php extension i.e "test.php" in C:\xampp\htdocs folder 
4) Now, in your web browser's address bar, type the address: http://localhost/test.php